# Blender site design: Captcha / 404 / Error page - input needed!

Tags: discussion

We are working on finishing touches for the site design, and one of the fun parts is coming up with the design concepts for the 404 / Error / Captcha pages. We generally like to have metaphors closely tied to the site's primary area of focus.

**So, what concepts or or ideas would you like to see for each of these pages related to Blender? If you have any clever ideas, we'd love for you to help us out!**

Examples of custom 404/error/captchas:

[Chemistry 404](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/404)

[Chemistry Error](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/error)

[Chemistry Captcha](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/captcha)

Comment: @MrZak Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Maybe a bit unimaginative.. But for the "something bad happened" page, perhaps some kind of [3D model gone wrong](http://pasteall.org/pic/98231) could work

Comment: For 404, a classic "not found" situation in blender is when [missing textures cause objects (or even the sky) to turn bright pink](https://www.google.com/search?&tbm=isch&q=blender%20missing%20texture). Perhaps not the easiest color to fit into an existing colorscheme though.. :P

Comment: For a captcha, maybe you could have Suzanne amongst a group of humans being put under the spotlight (or otherwise being 'singled out')

Comment: @gandalf3  How about a [sad looking](http://www.bing.com/images/search?q=sad+dog&FORM=HDRSC2) quadbot with some missing textures?  The quadbot is a fairly iconic Blender symbol with some more complexity (and thus easier to mess around with) than Suzanne.

Comment: @PGmath What's a quadbot..?

Comment: @gandalf3  Those things from Tears of Steel.  See my answer.

Comment: Looking at all the suggestions so far, my favorites are [David's broken blender](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/1020/5705) error, [Dontwalk's "I am not a monkey" Suzanne](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/1024/5705) captcha, and my (inspired by gandalf) [pink Quadbot](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/1018/1018) 404.

Comment: Any updates as to what is happening with this?

Comment: It's been a few months and [nothing's been done](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/bleah), anything going on with this?

Answer (score 13):

### Captcha

For the Captcha page I envision a picture of Proog from [elephants dream](https://orange.blender.org), redrawn in a style similar to world building's awesome [new site design](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2916/worldbuilding-site-design). Direct link to [the poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtSrG.jpg).

Elephants dream was all inside a machine, captcha pages are meant to discern users from machines.
[image: proog]

---

### Error

A picture of a broken blender. The glass shattered and the blade bent. (not in a box or looking like this picture)
[image: broken blender]
<sup>[source](http://www.fccfreeradio.com/pub-crawl-broken-blender-special/)</sup>

For anyone thinking that this joke is too overused, the error page is a perfect place to put it. This is the least viewed page of the three error pages; and a broken blender sure is an error.

---

### 404

perhaps a more stylized version of blender with nothing in it. (again going back to that [poster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dtSrG.jpg)) No text, no 3D view, just blender very lost. (and a real thing that [happens](https://blender.stackexchange.com/q/19582/2217)).
[image: blender with no text in interface]

Here are some good 404 pages from other network sites.
https://codereview.stackexchange.com/404
https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/404
https://travel.stackexchange.com/404
https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/404
https://workplace.stackexchange.com/404
and even
https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/404

Comment: I love the broken blender!

Comment: The broken blender error is great!  I don't really get the Captcha/Proog link though.  I also kind of like [Gandalf3's 404 suggestion](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/blender-site-design-captcha-404-error-page-input-needed?noredirect=1#comment4318_1017) better.

Comment: I agree with @PGmath

Answer (score 10):

Here are my concepts.  I decided to use the [Quad Bot from Tears of Steel](http://www.tearsofsteel.org) since I think it lends itself to manipulation and interpretation than Suzanne (and it works really well with the captcha).  Though it's not quite as obvious symbol of Blender as Suzanne, I personally at least see it used quite a bit in the Blender community and immediately recognize it as closely accosted with Blender.

---

### 404 not found:

Inspired by [gandalf3's suggestion](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1017/blender-site-design-captcha-404-error-page-input-needed#comment4318_1017) of using missing image textures.

[image]

---

### Error:

[image]

I do like [David's broken blender Idea](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/a/1020/5705) a lot too.  If someone can pull off a good render of it I'd go for that just as well.

---

### Captcha:

[image]
<sub>I accidentally rendered this one at low-res, low samples.  I'll fix that sometime.</sub>

The posing on this one could use a little work.
<sub>(I'm not too swift with armatures so if someone could give me a little guidance on how to move the feet on his rig that would be cool.)</sub>

I know the rendered Quad Bot doesn't technically fit with the minimalist flat look of the main site UI.  But I think it actually looks pretty good as long as the backdrop matches the site background color, it looks like he's sitting there on the page staring at you.

The Quad Bot is licensed **(CC) Blender Foundation | [mango.blender.org](https://mango.blender.org)**.

Comment: The continuity here is brilliant.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: I kind of like the idea with the tiling, but it doesn't really fit with everything else. I do like the "I am not a monkey" though.

Comment: I was going to suggest having the monkey scratching his chin for a 404, something akin to the thinker. Alternatively the Blender logo with the dot in the middle missing.

Answer (score 2):

**Captcha**:

The StackExchange network would like you to prove that you are not a robot. because *reasons*.

We'll let you continue if you can answer the following question correctly:

> This site offers support for Blender. What kind of Blender?

- A kitchen appliance designed to make delicious smoothies full of vitamin D3
- I don't care, as long as it *blends*.
- A program designed to let you create 3D models / animations

**Error**

Something happened. Give the site a few minutes to recover.
This is our fault not yours - try back later

**404**

The page you tried to connect to doesn't appear to exist any longer. If it was a question it may have been deleted by the person that posted it.

---

i'll add images later.

Comment: Just found this now. +1 for the captcha query :)

Comment: Cool concept. LOL :D