# Custom error/404 page status?

Tags: feature-request

It was almost two years ago that [the creation custom 404 and other error pages was offered](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1017/5705).  Several good ideas were presented and voted on, but there was no final official decision and we still have the [generic error and 404 pages](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/bleah).

Is there any way this effort can be resurrected?  I think it would be cool to have our own, and I really like some of the ideas presented (not just my own :P ).

Comment: We could also do something like the Blender Manual 404 page: https://docs.blender.org/manual/en/dev/404

Comment: I think more suggestions for page ideas should probably go on the original post (linked above).  Here I am inquiring as to the status of this project as it seems to have been somewhat forgotten.